# LINQ to Entites: How should I handle System.InvalidOperationException when checking for existance of an item?

Tags: exception, linq-to-entities

I have a many-to-one relationship that users can edit via checkboxes.  PK of Foo is ID, and fid contains the id from the checkbox.

I'm checking to see if an element exists with:

```
Foo ent;
try
{
  ent = ctx.Foo.First(f => f.ID == fid);
}
catch (System.InvalidOperationException ioe)
{
  ent = new Foo();
}
```

It seems to me that I should be able to do this without throwing an exception.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InvalidOperationException` you get has the message:

```
Sequence contains no matching element
```

The behaviour of `First` is that it throws this exception if the element is not found.

You can use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` and check for `null`. The null-coalescing operator (`??`) can be used to make this check.

```
Foo ent = ctx.Foo.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == fid) ?? new Foo();
```

Note also that there is a similar pair of functions, `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` that throw an exception if more than one matching element is found. In your specific case, assuming that the identities should be unique, it might be more appropriate to use `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Still throws an exception for me. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921701/linqs-ordefault-throws-exceptions-in-mvc3-activerecord