# LINQ's *OrDefault throws exceptions in MVC3 + ActiveRecord

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-activerecord

Spurred on by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640303/linq-to-entites-how-should-i-handle-system-invalidoperationexception-when-check/2640314), I decided to try this in my MVC3/ActiveRecord application.

I have a bunch of models already working, and some views that do stuff with those models. Nothing special here. One of my models is called `AppSession`.

Based on said question, I expected this to work: `AppSession.FirstOrDefault(a => ...) ?? null`.

It didn't work. I still get an `InvalidOperationException`. This is true of `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault`. I ended up wrapping my call in `try/catch` to get around it.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** As requested, the actual code is:

```
void getAnAppSession() {
    AppSession sessions = project.AppSessions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Ip == ip && a.MacAddress == macAddress && a.Platform == platform && a.Version == version && a.EndTime == null)
}
```

`ip`, `macAddress`, `platform`, and `version` are all method variables that are verifiably not null. My schema for `AppSessions` (and accordingly, properties on my class) includes:

- ID (int, not null)
- StartDate (DateTime, not null)
- EndDate (DateTime, null)
- Ip (string, not null)
- MacAddress (string, not null)
- Platform (string, not null)
- Version (string, not null)

Comment: Do you check appsession for null before calling firstordefault?

Comment: Can you post the actual code where you wrote `...`? Maybe that's the bit that throws the exception.

Comment: You don't need to write `?? null`. That doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: The ?? was referred to in the winning answer in the linked question. I did not check a => a != null, if that's what you mean. I won't post the actual code, because it won't make sense; okay, fine.

Comment: What is the message of the InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @MarkByers I added it because I, too, thought my code should work, but it doesn't. So I figured, maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @stephen.vakil same as the original question: `Sequence contains no matching element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `project.AppSessions` itself is null? That would cause the `FirstOrDefault()` method to throw an error.  You might want to check if that is null before calling `FirstOrDefault` and create a new AppSession object if it is null:

```
AppSession sessions = (project.AppSessions as AppSession ?? new AppSession())
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Ip == ip && 
                    a.MacAddress == macAddress && 
                    a.Platform == platform && 
                    a.Version == version && 
                    a.EndTime == null);
```

Comment: Bingo. Newbie mistake :) (okay, ORM complexity mistake)